# Determening if a list of bachelor courses has a prerequisite or not in python

Tags: python

I have to write a code that determines if a course has a prerequisite or not. In the list at the bottom the 2 courses are mathematics 2, and physics electro magnetics. When I run the code given it says that all the courses have a prerequisite, only the last "none" contains "No prerequisites". I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
fhand = open('ba1.txt')
    for i in fhand:
        courses = i.split(";")
        print(courses[1])
        if courses[1] == "none":
            print("No prerequisites")
        else: 
            print("There is a prerequisite")
```

---

> mathematics 1;none
>
> chemistry 1;none
>
> basics of physics;none
>
> geosciences;none
>
> principles of sustainability;none
>
> applied biological sciences;none
>
> introduction to informatics;none
>
> mathematics 2;mathematics 1:end
>
> physics electro magnetics;mathematics 1:end
>
> integrative project;none

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you able to make your post show a [mcve]?

Comment: @JackDeeth I hope it is better now.

Comment: @Quantum please dont use screenshots. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does the blank line after `none` in your output (even though you didn't add a `\n` in your `print(courses[1])` give you a hint? Try doing `print(courses[1] == "none")`, or even `print("|" + courses[1] + "|")` to see what's happening

Comment: you forgot about the whitespace characters... like "\n"

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: Instead of checking `courses[1] == "none\n"`, you should _remove_ the `\n` from the line before you `split()` it. Do `courses = i.strip().split(";")`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes it worked. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't have to worry about whitespace your condition could be
`if 'none' in courses[1]:`

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much!